# What to use? Parameterized class, abstract class or undefined type in Scala?

Tags: oop, scala

I have to implement a small graph library for my small Scala + [JMonkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) game. Library will deal with shortest path caching for further queries. I will have to attach additional user data (like reference to another object) to my Vertexes and Edges. How to implement this behavior?

With:
1. parameterized class `class Graph[A, B] {...}`, or
2. provide `abstract class Graph {...}` and implement user data variables later, or
3. provide `abstract class Graph {...}` and define `type A` inside the class?

Or maybe I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195) on this topic

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. In my case, abstract types will be more concise as it's not a collection oriented structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are also traits which are mix between interface and concrete implementation.